# Share favorites between sites

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible to import favorites tags over between sites?  For example, I have sql-server favorited on SO, Server Fault, and Code Review, and I had to add it seperately at each site.

Comment: Seriously, was setting three favourites really so hard? Have you considered the impact of your proposed change to those who want separate and distinct favourites on the sites they visit?

Comment: @John Gardeniers, i don't see how it would be that big an impact if you were given the option to "import" your favorites from another site.  the picture i had in mind was for people that might have, say 10, 20+ favorites (i know some people that could/would follow that many) that it would be nice to import from one site to another, especially since sites like so, sf, and cr do have an overlap when it comes to tags

Comment: my comment addressed your specific question about favourites carrying over between sites, not an optional import function, which is a whole other animal altogether.

Comment: @John Gardeniers, edited my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it via favorite tags across site, but you can create a tagset on http://stackexchange.com/filters/855/interesting-tags and browse from there if you like